# NoSuchMessageException on Spring Boot tests

Tags: java, spring-boot

I upgraded a working project from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.1 and the tests stopped working.

All the test classes are set up like:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyTest {
...
```

I also tried adding `@ImportAutoConfiguration(MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class)` to the test class to no avail.

The code fails when the `@RestControllerAdvice` tries to read any i18n message during a call to *MockMvc*:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'fimPeriodoApuracao.null' for locale 'en'.
at org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource.getMessage(DelegatingMessageSource.java:76) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
```

The message is autowired on the RestControllerAdvice:

```
@Autowired
public ExceptionController(MessageSource messageSource) {
    this.messageSource = messageSource;
}
```

This project has only the main *application.properties* and *message.properties* inside the *resources* directory in the main directory. There is no test configuration.